# Getting an error when trying to build the CubicPilot sample from the Unity Google Play plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

i just watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKmmxxErv6I&list=PLbjPvLkw5f22TJqAsuK4Kq1k11n4d9MWL&index=5) about the Google Play Games plugin for Unity, and readed about how to set it up [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

But i get this error when i try to build the CubicPilot sample:

Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19\android.jar" -d

I've followed all the steps to set it up but i was not really sure about the step called:
**"Additional instructions on building for Android on Windows"** (Im using windows 7)

My computer had no JAVA_HOME enviroment variable, so i tried to create one and set the path to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 (I had no idea what i was doing, but it didn't work)

The instructions said that i had to set it to:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45.
However, there were no **jdk1.7.0_45**, so i just set it to the **jre7** which was the only folder.

And i also didn't understand the "Add the Java SDK's bin folder to your PATH environment variable".

I hope someone can help me with the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How to change the path environment variable: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Just solved my problem by installing the Java6 SDK. Since it's not easily available, here's the link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7675123/jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe

Answer (score -1):

I never experienced this error on unity before, but i got some issues like that programming for google app engine and android apps.

So, try download the jdk and use it instead of the jre. it has more features for developers, many of my problems (in another environments) were solved when I passed to use the jdk.